# Why a String object has to be passed by reference?

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

In C#, for what I know, the passage of the parameters during a method call is by value. BUT when you use an object as an argument, what you pass is the reference of the object itself. This means that if you access (and modify) the value of a field inside an object, the updates will be seen once the method call is finished too.

So, if I modify the value of a String inside a method, it should be modified when the method call is terminated (since String is an object in C#). But this isn't true, in fact if I write:

```
public static void main (String []args){
  String s= "hello";
  method(s);
  System.Console.Writeline(s);
}

public void method (String s)
{s = "world";}
```

It will print "hello", and not "world". The only way to print "world" is to add the keyword `ref` in the method signature and call.

Why this happens? My answer (which I'd like that you confirm or correct) is that in C# String objects are immutable, so if I make s="world" actually the compiler is creating a new string object, but the reference to the object String s doesn't change (since the passage is by value).

In fact, if I print `s.getHashCode()` just before and after `method()` call, the two values are different.

What do you think about my explanation?

Comment: The method creates a new variable that points to the same space in memory. You're changing the variable in `method` to point to something else, but not the variable in `main`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So, if I modify the value of a String inside a method, it should be modified when the method call is terminated (since String is an object in C#). But this isn't true, in fact if I write:

You're not modifying the `String` object. You're modifying the *parameter* to refer to a different `String`. That's just changing a local variable, and is *not* seen by the caller.

The String reference is being passed by value, just like normal. You need to distinguish between changing the value of the *parameter*, and modifying the object that a parameter value refers to. You'll see exactly the same behaviour with your own class, even if it's mutable:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var p = new Person { Name = "Tom" };
        Method(p);
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    }

    static void Method(Person parameter)
    {
        parameter = new Person { Name = "Robin" };
    }
}
```

Now if in `Method` you made a change to the *object* instead, e.g.

```
static void Method(Person parameter)
{
    parameter.Name = "Robin";
}
```

... *then* you'd see a change to the output. But that's not modifying the parameter. The only reason that string's immutability is relevant is that it means the second version of `Method` above has no equivalent (in safe code) when the parameter is a string.

See [my article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more details.

Comment: This deals with the immutability of strings. Not parameter passing.

Comment: So (just to check if I understood correctly) you're telling me that when I call the method, the parameter points to the String object passed to the method as argument. But then, when I make the assignment inside the method, the parameters will point to another String object (since, like I said, String are immutable) which value is "world", and the original "hello" string didn't change at all, it's simply not pointed anymore! Am I correct or I still don't understand something?

Comment: @MattClark Both issues are relevant to the question.

Comment: @justHelloWorld: I'm saying that the value of `s` in `main` is copied to `s` in `method`, because that's what pass-by-value means. You then assign a new value to `s` in method, and that doesn't change the value of `s` in `main`, again because that's what pass-by-value means. You need to understand that the value of `s` is *not* a string, it's a reference... the rest is straightforward. (Imagine you had `int` values instead - you wouldn't expect `s = 10` in `method` to change the value of `s` in `main`, would you?)

Answer (score 2):

> So, if I modify the value of a String inside a method, it should be modified when the method call is terminated (since String is an object in C#).

Yes, that is 100% correct.  If you were able to modify the actual `string` instance, than the caller would be able to observe that change.

Of course, because `string` is immutable *there is no way for you to modify the string instance*.  That's what it means for it to be immutable.

Since you're not actually modifying the `string` instance, there is no modification for the caller to actually observe.

What you are doing in your code is not modifying the string instance, but rather modifying *the variable that is holding the reference to the string*.  That variable is a completely different variable from the local variable in your main method.  Modifying one does not affect the other (unless you use `ref`).

What you have are to completely different variables, each with a reference to a string.  If you change the string that both reference, then that change can be observed from either location.  Changing either variable to reference something new is not something the other variable can observe.

Comment: I'm actually wondering if some of this would be easier to explain if it were represented in C++. Not that I like working in the language more than I have to, but it's at least a little bit clearer about what each declaration refers to, very specifically.

Comment: @Katana314: Only if you were talking to someone who already knew C++. It shouldn't be easier or harder if starting from scratch. Syntax for the same thing is different between languages. However you explain what the syntax in C++ means, it should be no harder to explain what the equivalent syntax in C# means, in the same way.

Comment: @newacct Well, the difference being that in C++, the differences between pointers and value-types must be clearly delineated with a symbol. It would be a little bit like showing a young math student 3 dots and then 3 more dots instead of "3 + 3"; more work, but only to be shown as an incremental learning step. I remember early on, it took me some time learning on my own to understand where things were "references" in Java, and where they were "values".

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with strings immutability. It's the default behaviour of reference type variables. When you assign a new reference, you are changing the reference value of the variable. The other variables that references to the same location is not affected from that assignment. In your case, when you don't use `ref` the reference value of `s` will be copied into the `parameter`, like this:

```
string s = "hello"
string parameter = s;
```

After that if you assign a new reference to `parameter`, it will only change where `parameter` points to and won't affect `s`. when you use `ref` there is no copying.In that case you are *actually* passing a *reference* rather than a copy of the reference.That's why you can change the where `s` points to. And *again* it's true for all reference types not just string.

Comment: I totally understand your answer now, but I still think that in some way the string immutability property is still involved in some way, in fact:

Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it appear as if you can do this. For example, when you write this code, the compiler actually creates a new string object to hold the new sequence of characters, and that new object is assigned to b. The string "h" is then eligible for garbage collection.

So I think that immutability is involved someway

Comment: @justHelloWorld I explain in my answer the degree to which immutability is involved, which is to say tangentially.  That said, there is nothing about the syntax of `string` that would indicate that strings are mutable.  Their syntax is very indicative of an immutable object (which makes sense, given that it's immutable and all).

Comment: @justHelloWorld: Immutability is not involved. The same syntax has the same semantics regardless of mutability or immutability. In fact, the language has no idea that a type is mutable or immutable.